# Is it possible to measure the value in diagram and export using python plotly

Tags: python, plotly

plotly is complete new to me. A general question, is it possible to measure the value in diagram and export using python plotly?

suppose that I have a diagram,
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXGMr.png)

I can measure the values in diagram directly, how can I transfer these values back to my program? Further more is it possible to generate a line in this position by clicking the mouse button.

thanks for any ideas.

BR
Simon

Comment: The layout and data information of the drawn graph can be output with `fig.layout` and `fig.data`, but this is already there - the data is its own thing. What are you trying to convey with the transfer? See [here](https://plotly.com/python/configuration-options/#add-optional-shapedrawing-buttons-to-modebar) for the ability to draw lines and circles with user interaction.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I updated my script and now I can draw **line** in the diagram. Can I get also the value of this line, I mean value in x, y co-ordinate system? I want to realise this function: draw a line and get the line position.

Comment: As far as I know, I don't think you can get that value by user input only.

Comment: thanks a lot, btw do you know is it possible to add text in plotly charts interactively?

Comment: I don't think the user can dynamically input the data.